# monoid with three elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I try to find a monoid with three elements that it doesn't be a group but I can't.
Dose this monoid exist?
How can I find this?
If I can't,how can I prove this monoid dosen't exist?

Comment: How does the monoid's having only three elements entail existence of inverses?

Comment: Yes it has only three elements

Answer (score 4):

Try $\{-1,0,1\}$ with multiplication, or $\{0,1,x\}$ with $x^2=0$.

In fact there is a non-group monoid of order $n$ for all $n>2$: one idea is to adjoint a $0$ element to any multiplicative cyclic group of order $n-1$, or another is to adjoint $0$ and $1$ to any set and stipulate the product of any two nonidentity elements is $0$.

There is also a nonabelian monoid of any order $n>2$, given by adjoining $1$ to any set and stipulating that $xy=x$ for all $x,y$ in the set.

Comment: What if the monoid is assumed to be nonabelian?  Do you know which $n$ works?

Comment: @Batominovski Any $n>2$ still. Updated answer. (I'll leave it as an exercise to check associativity.)