# In a category with one object and three morphisms id, a, and b, what is $a \circ b$?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to understand basic category theory, and it seems to me like there are 3 possibilies: this composition could be any of the 3 morphisms 
(id, a, or b) without losing any properties of the category.

So are there several categories with one object and 3 morphisms? I feel as though there is only one, but then there is no concrete answer to $a \circ b$.

Thanks.

Comment: A category with one object is a monoid, so you’re asking about monoids with three elements. There’s no reason there should only be one of these, and in fact up to isomorphism I believe there are exactly two. As you say, the composite of a and b can be any of the 3 possibilities, and this produces 3 monoid structures, 2 of which are isomorphic.

Comment: You can think about $End(\ast)$ as a monoid under composition, so you are correct to say that there is no one concrete answer, since there are multiple structures for a monoid with three elements. 

Edit: I guess Qiaochu Yuan already got to this before me, but you should check out this answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137521/monoid-with-three-elements

Comment: This is kind of an ill-defined question, but is it appropriate to "name" morphisms in a category? What I mean is--I heard morphisms are in some way atomic; that is, they carry no information. I feel as though a name is nontrivial information.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be?

Comment: I've edited my comment.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Naming morphisms is no different from naming anything else in mathematics, like the edges of a graph or the elements of a group.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is more clear to me now.